# 1.5hr is normal drying time for condenser dryer? Miele

Tags: dryer

I have a Miele W3033 washer and a Miele T8013C condenser dryer.

T8013C is a 24 inch, electric, ventless, condenser dryer, that vents into the room through the front, looks like this: https://www.ajmadison.com/cgi-bin/ajmadison/T8013C.html.

For a load of clothes (filled to 80% full in the washer) washed using "Normal" program on W3033, it take 1.5hrs to dry using "Normal" program on T8013C.

If I touch the dryer door, it doesn't feel warm at all, just the same as when the dryer is off. The exhaust air feels warm, but not hot... Is the 1.5hr drying time normal?

BTW, I just cleaned all the lint traps and the condenser filter, they are as closed to being "factory clean" as I can get it.

Comment: post a question at Miele support site

Comment: How mch water did it remove from the clothes in that time? (you can tell by weighing them before/after)

Comment: condenser dryers do not produce a warm exhaust, instead they contain a dehumidifier that recycles most of the heat internally

Comment: Exactly. A traditional dryer removes water from clothing *by boiling it out* i.e. pushing tumbler temperatures above 212F, which requires expelling huge volumes (thousands of cubic feet) of wet hot air.  A condensing dryer removes water *by putting a tumbler in the same compartment as a dehumidifier*, so it only has to expel small volumes (far less than 1 cubic foot) of liquid water. There's no heat being added except for process heat (i.e. its natural inefficiency), warming the air to increase its water holding, but not heat-damaging clothes.

Comment: For others who have a condenser dryer, it would be great if you can post your drying time.

Answer (score 2):

For other who came to this thread... I contacted Miele, and the service rep responded to say 1.5hr is normal for a condenser dryer like mine.